# Delaying function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, liquid

I am trying to delay this function.

```
$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', hideModal);
```

When you click the button it "hides the popup box" however I would like to delay this about half a second instead of being instant.

I thought at first it would be easy. Ill just add .delay to the end.. (I thought) But its not working and the function still fires instantly...

```
$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', hideModal).delay( 800 );
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: jquery's `delay` is for animation effects. You want setTimeout

Comment: Oh okay! Is this how you do it? I am not sure how to add a timeout function to my current one.

setTimeout$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', hideModal), 3000);

Thanks!

Comment: No; [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) accepts as its first argument a function to execute. What you want to do is make your click handler fire off a setTimeout which will execute hideModal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **setTimeout** or the **queue**.

Usage with **setTimeout**.

It calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(hideModal, 800);
});
```

Usage with **queue**.

It adds your given function to a queue of functions to be executed on the matched element which is currently this and then execute the next function on the queue for the matched element(s) which is currently this again.

More details [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/call-a-function-after-some-time-in-jquery.php).

```
$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', function() {
    $(this).delay(800).queue(function() {
        hideModal();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Hamms said, use `setTimeout` like so:

```
$(".add2cartPopEffect").on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(hideModal, 500);
});
```

Comment: Its not working but that could be my fault. For example the same button is set to "showModal"

But if i make a function to hide it. Of course the "Modal" never shows.

But if I delay it... Shouldnt it show the modal and than hide it half a second later?

When I use your code it simply shows the modal but doesnt hide it again.

But when i use my original code it just instantly hides it. 

Thanks!

Comment: It probably has something to do with your `hideModal` function using the `this` variable, can you post that code?

Comment: This?

  // Escape key closes cart
      $(document).keyup( function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
          switch (settings.method) {
            case 'flip':
            case 'drawer':
              hideDrawer();
              break;
            case 'modal':
              hideModal();
              break;
          }
        }
      });

Comment: I appreciate the help! The other answer above worked for me instantly. Much <3!